# Ошибка при выполнении SQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Писал код на C# и при запуске программы выскакивает данное сообщение:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Что следует сделать, чтобы от этого избавиться?

```
    private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String loginUser = Login.Text;
        String passUser = Password.Text;

        DB db = new DB();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = #uL AND `password` = #uP", db.getConnection());
        command.Parameters.Add("#uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
        command.Parameters.Add("#uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Yse");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал: [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netcore-3.0)

Видимо, ты перепутал # и @

Comment: Да, спасибо что помог)